# Linux Mint 17.2 screen resolution

Tags: linux, screen, resolution, linux-mint, xrandr

I am fresh new on linux and tring to connect on a TV 
http://www.cnet.com/products/samsung-ln-s325d/specs/ using DVI.
Problem: The screen resolution isn't good :(
I've tried many things with the xrandr command, but in the end, the new mode just doesn't work (black screen).

Here is the terminal:

```
frank@frank-Mint ~ $ cvt 1366 768
# 1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798     -hsync +vsync
frank@frank-Mint ~ $ xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440     1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
frank@frank-Mint ~ $ xrandr --addmode DVI-1 "1368x768_60.00"
```

From there,

```
frank@frank-Mint ~ $ xrandr --output DVI-1 --mode 1368x768_60.00
```

or system settings > Display >1368x768 (16:9)

just gives me a black screen saying the mode is not available

I have tried many other resolutions, but any custom resolutions do that.

Anyone have an idea?
thanks! :)

EDIT:

```
frank@frank-Mint ~ $ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 720, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-1 connected primary 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y     axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1280x720       60.0*+   59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     60.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        60.0     59.9  
   1368x768_60.00   59.9  
   1024x768_60.00   59.9
```

The last 2 are added

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Got it. Needed to upgrate graphic card driver lol

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
xrandr --output DVI-1 --mode "1368x768_60.00"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and  **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.